# What are these techniques or common singing styles called?

Tags: terminology, technique

I am looking to know if there is a name for two "techniques" or "singing styles" that I have found commonly in many songs.
The first, is a sudden change in the the voice of the singer for a particular line. Here are a few examples.

1. Cruel summer, when Taylor goes, "He looks up grinning like a devil." Here's the link with the at the right time.
2. Miss Americana and the Heartbreak prince, when she goes, "Go!", "fight!" and "win!" for the second time. Here's the link.

The second is a random onomatopoeia which the singer goes on as a tangent to the song.
Here are some examples.

1. You'll be back, from Hamilton.
2. Candyman by Christina Aguilera

Answer (score 1):

The first of the examples has nothing to do with the singer doing something different with her voice. The line "He looks up grinning like a devil" sounds different firstly because it's almost unaccompanied, and principally because there is heavy [reverb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverberation) on it, which makes it sound like she's singing from the back of a large room.

The technique used on the last two examples (singing without text) is most generally known as "vocalise". Closely related is ["scat singing"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scat_singing), an improvised vocalise.

Comment: What about the second example in the first question? (Miss Americana)

Comment: @HardikRajpal I don't hear anything special there

Comment: So are those words sung by the same singer or is it a group of background singers?

Comment: @HardikRajpal There are no background singers [credited](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lover_(album)#Personnel) for that track, so Taylor Swift sang all of it.

Comment: If it's all Taylor then you must admit that something's different about the way those words are sung and I am asking what it is.

Comment: @HardikRajpal Multitracking plus reverb